# How do I make Angular 8 compatible with IE11?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, polyfills

I upgraded to Angular 8 using `ng update`. It ran its migration scripts which (among other things) removed the es6/es7 imports in `polyfills.ts`. From what I read, Angular will create a special build for older browsers (including IE11) and I don't have to worry about polyfills anymore? I updated `browserlist` to be `not IE 9-10` instead of `not IE 9-11` to (I presume) hint that it should build the appropriate polyfills.

Unfortunately, after running `ng build`, I get some polyfill related errors, eg. `Reflect.getMetadata is not a function` and `Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'`. I tried putting `reflect` and `array` imports back into polyfills and move past those errors, but I get others. What's the deal? Am I supposed to include polyfills or not?

How do I make Angular 8 work with IE11?

Comment: you have that issue with  ng serve ?

Comment: @FatehMohamed `ng serve` doesn't work on IE11, but that's by design. My problem is after running `ng build`. Just edited to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try with `ng build --prod`? The normal build which uses the JIT compiler requires the Reflect polyfill and will not work on IE11.

Comment: @AvinKavish no, but I ran it using the `-c` flag and specified a configuration that uses aot

Comment: If I run `npx browserlist` I see IE11 in the list, so I don't think that's it, but I'll give it a try.

Comment: Aight, you should see two separate bundles once the build command is run. https://jaxenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/differential-loading-768x379.png
I'm still not sure how you get errors regarding Reflect if AOT has been used. It's mentioned in the docs that Reflect is only used by JIT.

Comment: @AvinKavish I see two separate bundles, that's working. My project uses some non-Angular decorators and (afaik) therefore requires Reflect. But Angular should at least have some detection for `Array.includes`, right? Why would it automatically remove it if we would need to put it back?

Comment: Here's a feature request to define separate polyfills for es5 vs. es2015 https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14168

Answer (score 11):

One way to get *IE 11* to work with *Angular 8* is to disable **differential loading**.

Do the following:

1. Update `tsconfig.json` with `"target": "es5"`
2. Update `polyfills.ts` with `import 'core-js'; // core-js@^3.1.4`

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted because it saved my life. Ok, differential loading is disabled, but it is not a big deal. I had no errors in IE11 so no idea what went wrong.

Comment: @Robouste I didn't downvote, but this answer is equivalent in quality to "just don't use angular 8". While it technically solves the problem, it's not the answer most of us are looking for.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the ideal solution, even though it works :(

Comment: I think the expectation that IE11 ought to work with differential loading is too optimistic. From another [source](https://auth0.com/blog/angular-8-differential-loading/): _One very important note about this: See that not IE 9-11 part? If you need to support those browsers, you can remove the not, but it comes at a price. Those versions of Internet Explorer can’t take advantage of differential loading, so it will be disabled._

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what differential loading is.  It sounded like it was going to detect the browser, and load es5 for IE and es2015 for modern browsers.  At least that's the impression I got from reading about differential loading in the release announcements.  I guess I was reading too much between the lines.  If it can't serve up different bundles based on browser capabilities, what *can* differential loading do?

Comment: As much as I'd like to not use this suggestion it works, It's just easier to test and since differential loading isn't even used locally from serve command, disabling it while you test on your local machine doesn't hurt.

Comment: Do you have some more info on that second adjustment? The tsconfig.json adjustments makes sence to me. But what does the import in polyfills.ts do? Why is that necessary? Do you have a link or resource for that adjustment?

Comment: polyfills.ts is Angular way of adding all the functionality to those browsers that do not support more advanced JavaScript features by default. core.js is the main library that Angular uses.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to serve your app to ES5 browsers like IE11 as well as modern ES2015+ browsers like Chrome and Firefox, add additional build configuration to your angular.json to serve your app's ES5 bundle.

1. Add a new "es5" configuration to the `architect` section of angular.json:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "my-app": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "es5" : {
              "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.es5.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "configurations": {
            "es5": {
              "browserTarget": "my-app:build:es5"
}}}}}}}
```

2. Create `tsconfig.app.es5.json` alongside `angular.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5"
    }
}
```

3. Update `browserslist` to enable IE 11 support. Make sure browserslist is in the root directory of your app, alongside the `angular.json` file. For example:

```
not IE 9-10 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
IE 11
```

4. Add a new start script to `package.json` to use the ES5 configuration you created in step 1:

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "ng build",
  "buildES5": "ng build --configuration=es5",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "startES5": "ng serve --configuration=es5",
}
```

Now you can build and serve your app for legacy browsers that only support ES5 or modern browsers that support ES2015+:

- `npm run build` builds your app for modern browsers
- `npm run buildES5` builds your app for legacy browsers
- `npm run start` builds and serves your app for modern browsers
- `npm run startES5` builds and serves your app for legacy browsers

Comment: This only considers `ng serve`. Can you add more details to support using `ng build`?

Comment: The build step in angular.json already included an equivalent "ES5" configuration however I failed to demonstrate a package.json script to run the build independent of the serve. I updated the original post to clarify build vs. serve.

Comment: This is useful information; however this isn't really differential loading, is it?  Either you build it with ES5 only support or with ES2015+ only support; they are two separate commands.  Is there any possible way to have your cake (build both bundles) and eat it too (use both IE and Chrome simultaneously with their respective bundles)?

Comment: Your right. Out of the box, you can get the Angular CLI to generate a single version of the app with support for differential loading. All you need to do is update the browserlist file to enable support for IE 11 (same as what I demonstrated in my original comment) and run a normal ng build. The resulting index.html file will contain script references to ES2015 scripts that modern browsers will use and ES5 versions of the scripts that only get used by older browsers (thanks to the new nomodule attribute).

Comment: See the official instructions here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#configuring-serve-for-es5

Comment: @BrianDeSousa, will running ng serve run application for both es5 and es2015 or do we need to run them separately ? Also, per my understanding if we target es5, wont we loose es2015 functionality ?

Comment: Hi @Maddy, with this solution you have to run them both separately. It's been a while since I have looked at this but since these are compiler options and you are using Typescript, you can still code with ES2015 functionality but at compile time, the typescript compiler will build something that is compatible with the target browser using polyfills and such.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my `polyfill.ts` issues with `IE 11` by doing the following:

1. Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`
2. Uncomment line `import 'web-animations-js'`  inside `polyfill.ts`
3. Change `target` value from **'es2015' to 'es5'** inside `tsconfig.json`.

`IE 11` requires 'es5'.

Comment: Targeting ES5 effectively disables differential loading, and Angular 8 will only build one set of code as it did in Angular 2-7. You're disabling the Angular 8 optimization in question. So while this technically works, it's not the right answer.

Comment: I am perfectly aware of that but we have lived without differential loading before :) dont get me wrong, I really support your request regarding polyfills, because like it is now, differential loading is in no use, its like unfinished... In my case and I must say unfortunately, I need to choose IE 11 consumers over differential loading...

Answer (score 0):

If you want `ng serve` to build the app for "es5" by default.

*angular.json*

```
"architect": {
  "build": {
    ...
    "configurations": {
      "development": {
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig-es5.app.json"
      },
      ...
    }
  },
  "serve": {
    ...
    "options": {
      "browserTarget": "bludesk-web:build:development"
    },
    ...
  }
```

*browserlist*

```
...
IE 11
not IE 9-10
```

*tsconfig-es5.app.json*

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Angular CLI _by default_ disables differential loading during development, "The ng serve, ng test, and ng e2e commands, however, generate a single ES2015 build which cannot run in older browsers that don't support the modules, such as IE 11." - [docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#local-development-in-older-browsers)

Comment: Ok, I'll modify my answer then. Thank you