# Angular 8 application is not working in IE11, But in Edge it's working fine, How to fix it, recently i migrated my app from angular 7 to 8

Tags: angular, angular8

> Angular 8 application is not working in IE11, but in Edge it's working fine. How to fix it, I recently migrated my app from Angular 7 to 8.

And I added the below code in `polyfills.ts`

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
 import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
```

Comment: Make sure you have changed your browserslist file to support IE11

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make Angular 8 compatible with IE11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563742/how-do-i-make-angular-8-compatible-with-ie11)

Answer (score 1):

also add classlist & hammer JS and try

```
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
import 'hammerjs';
```

Comment: It works thanks :), but could you explain a bit why?

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem but it was because of `ng serve`, if I build it it will compile just fine. I think it has to do with angular 8 using es2015 instead of es15 and IE doesn't recognize that