# Angular 8 app is not opening in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, internet-explorer-11, angular8

I am new to `Angular 8` and currently developing a `web-app` in it. It is working fine in `Google Chrome` and `EDGE` but it is not even being load in `IE 11`. I explored for the solution over the internet and tried some suggested solution.

What I tried is:

---

**Attempt 01:**

Pasted this lines of code in `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
```

**Attempt 02**

Added these lines in `polyfills.ts`

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
 import 'core-js/es/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es/object';
 import 'core-js/es/function';
 import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es/number';
 import 'core-js/es/math';
 import 'core-js/es/string';
 import 'core-js/es/date';
 import 'core-js/es/array';
 import 'core-js/es/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es/map';
 import 'core-js/es/set';
```

**Attempt 03**

Included support of `IE 9-11` in `browserlist` file.

---

But all in vain and I couldn't resolved this issue. **Can someone please identify what am I doing wrong!**

Comment: clear ie browser cache and try again

Comment: I have tried that already. Even I stopped caching but it didn't worked.

Comment: have you tried changing your target in `tsconfig.json` from `es2015` to `es5`?
there are several answers on SO dealing with that issues
e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563742/how-do-i-make-angular-8-compatible-with-ie11 or

Comment: In attempt 1, did you try to change from content="IE=edge"  to content="IE=11"?

Comment: @Arikael I read somewhere that its not a good solution if you are working in `angular 8`.

Comment: it isn't but might be worth checking to see if that's the problem.
Otherwise there is this comment -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/57368223/885338

Comment: @Arikael It works fine in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 8 project not working in Microsoft Edge and IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57362323/angular-8-project-not-working-in-microsoft-edge-and-ie11)

Answer (score 2):

By default in angular version 8, differential loading for `ng build` is enabled. However for `ng test` and `ng serve`, it only generates a single ES2015 build which cannot run in IE11.

There're two ways to have ES5 code during serve which make angular 8 app work in IE11.

1. Disable differential loading completely. (**Not recommended**)

   You can turn differential loading off by changing the target from **"es2015"** to **"es5"** in your **tsconfig.json**.
2. Have multiple configurations for serve.

   Create a new tsconfig tsconfig-es5.app.json next to tsconfig.app.json with the below contents:

   ```
   { 
    "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
    "compilerOptions": { 
    "target": "es5"   
     }
   }
   ```

   In your angular.json add two new configuration section (es5 node) under the build and serve target to provide a new tsconfig.

   ```
   "build": {
       "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
       "options": {
           ...
   },
   "configurations": {
   "production": {
       ...
   },
   "es5": {
       "tsConfig": "./tsconfig-es5.app.json"
   }
   }
   },
   "serve": {
   "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
   "options": {
       ...
   },
   "configurations": {
   "production": {
   ...
   },
   "es5": {
       "browserTarget": "<your application name>:build:es5"
   }
   }
   },
   ```

   Besides, the browserslist file content as below:

   ```
   > 0.5%
   last 2 versions
   Firefox ESR
   not dead
   IE 9-11 # For IE 9-11 support, remove 'not'.
   ```

   You can then run the serve with this configuration using the below command:

   ```
   ng serve --configuration es5
   ```