# IE11 issue of angular8 application

Tags: angular

I am working on angular8 application which works fine on chrome, Firefox, Opera, Edge. But not in IE11 and Safari browser.

This is my pollyfills.ts

```
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es/set';  
import 'core-js/es/reflect';
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
```

When i hit url in IE11 getting this error[image]

Also i checked index.html for pace js which is not present. Can any one let me know what mistake i had done in the setup.

Comment: it says it runs in dev mode. how does it behave in production mode?

Comment: @Ifaruki .. It's not related to the dev or production mode...

Comment: Can you expand the error and update the ui erro stack?

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is already an answer here:

[How do I make Angular 8 compatible with IE11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563742/how-do-i-make-angular-8-compatible-with-ie11)

Basically you need to change the browserlist file and the compilerOptions target to es5.

Cheers

Comment: Browserlist file i changed and compilerOptionf has been set to es5. But still facing the error.

Comment: What happens if you expand the error given in the console log? Maybe you are using some functions which are unsupported in IE.